# Get network address using ip and mask. (php, IPv6)

Tags: php, ipv6

How to get the first ip address on the network (using ipv6) (php)
Example:

```
input - d7a:5949:11d0:bd9e:b2c1:6268:d889:de9b / 48
output- d7a:5949:11d0::
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start address of a network is computed by setting all host bits of the mask to zero. In other words, it's a simple bit-wise AND of the address and the mask.

Use [inet_pton](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) to parse the IP address. There is no function in the standard library that produces binary network masks, so you have to write that one yourself:

```
<?php

function mask(int $bits, int $ones): string
{
    $m = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $bits/8; $i++) {
        if ($ones >= 8) {
            $m .= chr(0xff);
            $ones -= 8;
        } else {
            $m .= chr(~(0xff >> $ones));
            $ones = 0;
        }
    }

    return $m;
}

$addr = inet_pton("d7a:5949:11d0:bd9e:b2c1:6268:d889:de9b");
$mask = mask(128, 48);

$start = $addr & $mask;

echo inet_ntop($start), "\n"; // d7a:5949:11d0::
```

Try it on 3v4l.org: https://3v4l.org/hrD6a

Comment: I forgot to limit `$ones` in the mask function. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Peter- Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I have created my own class IpUtils. You can find the class [here](https://github.com/jspit-de/IpUtils). This makes your task very easy to solve.

```
$ip = IpUtils::create('d7a:5949:11d0:bd9e:b2c1:6268:d889:de9b/48');
echo $ip->netAdr(); // d7a:5949:11d0::
```